# Capturing both stderror and stdout from external code while using tqdm

Tags: python, windows, tqdm

I'm trying to write a context manager that can capture both stdout and stderr while using the tqdm progress bar library on Windows, working through the command line. Note that the existing solutions in contextlib do *not* work as the text I need to capture come from a .dll called via ctypes. I've managed to adapt code from [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/) to capture stdout *or* stderr, but I am unable to combine them both without breaking tqdm. Below, please find two MWEs.

```
import time
import tqdm
import ctypes
import contextlib
import sys, os, io
import tempfile

libc = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt

@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout_capture(tfile):
    # The original fd stdout points to. Usually 1 on POSIX systems.
    original_stdout_fd = sys.stdout.fileno()

    def _redirect_stdout(to_fd):
        """Redirect stdout to the given file descriptor."""
        # Flush and close sys.stdout - also closes the file descriptor (fd)
        sys.stdout.close()

        # Make original_stdout_fd point to the same file as to_fd
        os.dup2(to_fd, original_stdout_fd)

        # Create a new sys.stdout that points to the redirected fd
        sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(os.fdopen(original_stdout_fd, 'wb'))

    # Save a copy of the original stdout fd in saved_stdout_fd
    saved_stdout_fd = os.dup(original_stdout_fd)

    try:
        # Create a temporary file and redirect stdout to it
        _redirect_stdout(tfile.fileno())

        # Yield to caller
        yield

        # The context has closed, reset the redirector
        _redirect_stdout(saved_stdout_fd)

    finally:
        os.close(saved_stdout_fd)


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stderr_capture(tfile):
    # The original fd stderr points to. Usually 1 on POSIX systems.
    original_stderr_fd = sys.stderr.fileno()

    def _redirect_stderr(to_fd):
        """Redirect stderr to the given file descriptor."""
        # Flush and close sys.stderr - also closes the file descriptor (fd)
        sys.stderr.close()

        # Make original_stderr_fd point to the same file as to_fd
        os.dup2(to_fd, original_stderr_fd)

        # Create a new sys.stderr that points to the redirected fd
        sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(os.fdopen(original_stderr_fd, 'wb'))

    # Save a copy of the original stderr fd in saved_stderr_fd
    saved_stderr_fd = os.dup(original_stderr_fd)

    try:
        # Create a temporary file and redirect stderr to it
        _redirect_stderr(tfile.fileno())

        # Yield to caller
        yield

        # The context has closed, reset the redirector
        _redirect_stderr(saved_stderr_fd)

    finally:
        os.close(saved_stderr_fd)


def read_buffer(stderr_buffer):
    stderr_buffer.flush()
    stderr_buffer.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
    err = stderr_buffer.read().decode("utf-8").strip()
    stderr_buffer.truncate(0)
    stderr_buffer.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)

    return err


# Define temporary files to capture the redirects
errfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode = 'w+b')
outfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode = 'w+b')
```

So the above are the adapted definitions for capturing stdout and stderr, which seem to work just fine. What follows are three variants on capturing stderr and stdout, with varying degrees of functionality.

This uses tqdm's standard output, which outputs the values on stderr. Thus, if I output on to stdout with libc and capture the stdout, this works just fine.

```
for _ in tqdm.tqdm(range(3)):
    with stdout_capture(outfile):
        libc.puts(f"foo".encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(1)
print(read_buffer(outfile))
```

This uses tqdm outputting to stdout instead of stderr, and captures stderr instead. Again, this functions.

```
for _ in tqdm.tqdm(range(3), file = sys.stdout):
    with stderr_capture(errfile):
        libc.perror(f"foo".encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(1)
print(read_buffer(errfile))
```

Now, I want to capture both stdout and stderr within the context defined. However, this just breaks tqdm entirely! The bar freezes at the 0/3 position until the code finishes, and then prints out both buffers as expected.

```
for _ in tqdm.tqdm(range(3), file = sys.stdout):
    with stdout_capture(outfile):
        with stderr_capture(errfile):
            libc.perror(f"foo".encode("utf-8"))
            libc.puts(f"bar".encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(1)
print(read_buffer(outfile))
print(read_buffer(errfile))
```

Comment: You're closing the file handle used for the progress bar. You'll need to find a way to keep the original ``sys.__stdout__`` and ``sys.__stderr__`` attached to the console while moving file descriptors 1 (STDOUT) and 2 (STDERR) to point to the files. Then you can use ``sys.__stdout__`` or ``sys.__stderr__`` for your progress bar.